# $\sum a_n $ absolutely convergent and $\sum b_n $ convergent $\implies \sum a_nb_n$ absolutely convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is this true?

$\sum a_n $ absolutely convergent and $\sum b_n $ convergent $\implies \sum a_nb_n$ absolutely convergent.

I don't know how to proceed .Please help.

Comment: Is the product a cauchy product? i.e. $\sum_{k=0}^na_nb_{n-k}$ or simply  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nb_n$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: If $\sum b_n$ converges, then $|b_n|<1$ for $n$ large (as $b_n \to 0$) and so

$$|a_n b_n | < |a_n|$$

for $n$ large.

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ absolutely converge, then $\sum\sqrt{|a_nb_n|}$ converges, as

$$0\le2\sqrt{|a_nb_n|}\le |a_n|+|b_n|$$

And $|a_nb_n|<1$ for $n$ large and so
$$|a_nb_n|<\sqrt{|a_nb_n|}$$